# Sending and receiving JSON data | PhoneGap + Jquery Mobile app using ajax()

Tags: ajax, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a PhoneGap application with jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 & jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1. I have a login form with a username and a password. There is a JSON api which can send and receive JSON data for processing the login.

I use the following JavaScript for the ajax login.

```
$('#submit').bind('click', function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : "http://domainx/public/login",
        xhrFields  : {withCredentials: true},
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();},
        complete   : function() {$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();},
        data       : {username : 'subin', password : 'passwordx'},
        dataType   : 'json',
        success    : function(response) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error      : function() {
            console.error("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my html code for the login form.

```
<div data-role="content">
     <form id="login-form" data-ajax="false" method="post">
        <fieldset>
           <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="subin" placeholder="Username">
           <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="passwordx" placeholder="Password">
           <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" data-icon="plus">
        </fieldset>
     </form>
  </div>
```

But this just don't work. The server returns login failure error, although it works fine for other apps.

Comment: Do you solve this.I got the same error.Cant solve the problem with these answers

Comment: @Sunny IIRC, my issue was with the server side. Please read the accepted Answer and its comments.

Comment: Its working in POSTMAN .but not in phonegap application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several error is your code:

1. Change date to data

   ```
   data       : {username : 'subin', password : 'passwordx'},
   ```
2. Remove this line, it will prevent Phonegap from successful posting:

   ```
   xhrFields  : {withCredentials: true},
   ```
3. In your beforeSend and complete use this function to show loader:

   ```
   $.mobile.loading('show');
   ```

   and

   ```
   $.mobile.loading('hide');
   ```

   your current ones are deprecated in jQuery 1.2+.

Your final code should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type       : "POST",
    url        : "http://domain/public/login",
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
    complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
    data       : {username : 'subin', password : 'passwordx'},
    dataType   : 'json',
    success    : function(response) {
        //console.error(JSON.stringify(response));
        alert('Works!');
    },
    error      : function() {
        //console.error("error");
        alert('Now working!');                  
    }
});
```

Proof that it is working, just run it from the disk and not from a server because you will get a CROSS domain error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>          
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
    $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : "http://domain/public/login",
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
        complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
        data       : {username : 'subin', password : 'passwordx'},
        dataType   : 'json',
        success    : function(response) {
            //console.error(JSON.stringify(response));
            alert('Works!');
        },
        error      : function() {
            //console.error("error");
            alert('Not working!');                  
        }
    });     
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried your final code, and it looks like it works from the server too. I'm not getting a cross domain error - and it's deployed to my Ipad.

Comment: Actually the typo wasn't there in the code. Still the code doesn't work. :( Could be a server side issue as well, let me try.

Comment: Also, I cannot remove `xhrFields  : {withCredentials: true}` since the api needs to be contacted in a session free manner.

Comment: Unfortunately my example didn't work with that line. As soon as I removed it everything success callback was executed.

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure it out and will update you. I'm accepting this answer. Thanks @Gajotres

Answer (score 1):

You have a type here:

```
    date       : {username : 'subin', password : 'passwordx'},
//--^^^^----this should be named data
```

try changing to this:

```
    data       : {username : 'subin', password : 'passwordx'},
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo note, it was not there in the code since I changed it after posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

use datatype jsonp

```
 dataType   : 'jsonp'
```

enables cross domain

Comment: Please don't only provide a link, mention the relevant stuff